# join with lookup and group by

Tags: sql, oracle

i have 2 tables like below:

lk_premier:

```
code descr
P    Premier
N    Non Premier
```

Case:

```
id  taxPin  
1   123     
2   789
```

Status:

```
id voting_status premier
1   5               P
1   5               P
1   5               P
2   5               P
2   5               N
2   5               null
3   5               null
3   5               null
3   5               null
3   5               null
3   5               null
```

I used the below sql

```
select
        decode(premier,
        'P',
        'PREMIER',
        'N',
        'NON PREMIER') as caseStatus,
        count(*) as count   
    from
        status s,
        case c
    where
        c.id = s.id 
        and c.id = 1  
        and s.voting_status = 5  
    group by
        premier
```

I want to join the lk_premier table, so my output looks like for id=2,

```
caseStatus  count
PREMIER     1
NON PREMIER 1
```

for id = 3

```
caseStatus  count
PREMIER     0
NON PREMIER 0
```

Comment: why not just join on the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never do joins this way -- this way of doing joins was depreciated about 20 years ago.  the join should look like this:

```
join status s on c.id = s.id
```

once you do joins the right way then how you do left joins is easier as seen below:

here you go

```
select
    coalesce(p.desc,'unknown') as caseStatus,
    count(*) as count   
from case c
join status s on c.id = s.id
left join lk_premier p on p.code = c.premier 
where c.id = 1  and s.voting_status = 5  
group by coalesce(p.desc,'unknown')
```